# How to have bot automatically disconnect after playing audio file

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

After my bot reads the audio file, I need it to leave the channel. I've tried to put an "await voice.disconect()" in the line but that disconnected the bot after it joined the channel. How do I implement this in to make the bot leave after playing the file?

```
#imports
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
import random
from discord import embeds
from discord import message
from discord import guild
from discord_slash import SlashCommand

#define client & prefix
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')

#list of audio for random.choice
Audio = ['LIST OF AUDIO FILES']

#join & play file command
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def yolk(ctx):
    if (ctx.author.voice):
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        voice = await channel.connect()
        source = FFmpegPCMAudio(random.choice(Audio))
        player = voice.play(source)
    else:
        await ctx.send("User not in a voice channel, unable to connect.")

client.run('BOT TOKEN')
```

Comment: Have you tried sleeping before disconnecting? (sleeping as in `await asyncio.sleep(secs)`

Comment: @12944qwerty Thank you so much! I did not even know this was a thing! Now since I do that actually can solve so many other problems! Thanks bro.

Answer (score 1):

There is after parameter that you can pass it to `voice.play`. So you can do it with

```
voice.play("audio.mp3", after=await voice.disconnect())
```

I didn't try it with async function but i guess that will work.